# What is the best way to learn more about imperative-style concurrent programming?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

Have had to write my first "proper" multithreaded coded recently, and realised just how little I knew about how "imperative-style" (ie, concurrency models used by C++/C#/Java, and the like) concurrent programming techniques.

What resources are there (both books and online tutorials, etc) in order to learn more about this area of coding-fu?

NB: I'm not asking about concurrency models that are arguably better (Erlang's message passing, or Clojure's STM), just paradigms used in imperative languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Patterns for Parallel Porgramming](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/reviews/patterns_for_parallel_programming_review.html) is a good general book on concurrent programming techniques. It uses Java threads, OpenMP in C and MPI in C for the examples.

Pretty much any decent book on multithreaded programming in any of the languages you mention should cover the general principles. I'm covering this ground in [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.manning.com/williams/), for example.

Comment: does the  C++ Concurrency in Action book cover the techniques and models?

Comment: C++ Concurrency in Action covers how to use concurrency in C++. It describes various techniques and models, such as parallel algorithms, actors and message passing, shared state, and tasks and thread pools.

Answer (score 6):

[Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) is one of the most approachable and thorough overviews of this topic, especially if you are using Java (although I think it's useful even if you're not).

Answer (score 4):

Doug Lea's [Concurrent Programming in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310090) is an excellent book on the topic (though it is of course Java-specific).

Answer (score 1):

You might find my [Java Concurrency refcard](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/core-java-concurrency) a useful short reference for Java-specific questions.